# Proper styling for a semantic definition list

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I have a list of key-value-pairs. As I want to go semantic, I chose a definition list for the purpose (see snippet). This is ONE way I need to display the definition list:

[image: This is the way I need to display the definition list:]

Does anybody of you css gurus have any idea how to achieve this with the given markup and pure css? Using different markup for different visual representations of the content seems to be a really bad idea. In other cases I need to display the identical HTML as follows:

[image: Second way to display the list.]

And in some rare cases I even need it like this:

[image: Third variant.]

```css
/*prepared so you can quickly start hacking your style rules*/
dl {
  
}

dt {
  
}

dd {
  
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Actual sales this year</dt>
  <dd>38,500 $</dd>
  <dt>Sales last year</dt>
  <dd>72,000 $</dd>
  <dt>Expected sales this year</dt>
  <dd>78,000 $</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: It has to work on older IEs as well, so it'd better be no css 3. But even if you chose to go css 3 and flex box, how would you achieve this? The lists vary in length. Also, the textual descriptions in the `<dt>` vary in length (different languages).

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and what about it isn't working? That's the sort of question SO is for, not general "here's what I need, please make it"

Comment: Looks like tabular data. A small table, but tabular nonetheless.

Comment: Just ignore the second and third display variation; I added those only to make clear that it is a really bad idea to use a table, since you cannot create the 3 slightly different visual representations on the same markup using a table. Problem is that usually to achieve a visual result like in the first picture, you'd need a wrapper around the pair of `<dt><dd>`. In a definition list, there is no wrapper available since the only allowed child elements of a `<dl>` are `<dt>` and `<dd>`.